# Reference request: $L^p$ regularity for elliptic differential operators

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I am looking for a book that proves the following:

> Let $M$ be a closed manifold, $L$ an elliptic differential operator on $M$ of order $k$ and with smooth coefficients. Suppose $u$ is a distribution on $M$ such that $Lu\in L^p$ ($1<p<\infty$), i.e., there exists $v\in L^p$ such that $\langle u,L^*\phi\rangle=\int_Mv\,\phi$ for all smooth $\phi$, where $L^*$ is the formal adjoint of $L$, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the dual pairing of distributions and test functions. Then $u\in W^{k,p}$ and $\|u\|_{W^{k,p}}\leq C(\|Lu\|_{L^p}+\|u\|_{L^p})$.

The case $k=2$ is discussed in many books on elliptic PDEs. Also, it seems that the case $p=2$ appears in many books, for example the first volume of M. E. Taylor's trilogy *Partial Differential Equations*. However, I have not found a proof for the general case. Here are my questions:

1. Does this result necessarily rely on the theory of pseudodifferential operators?
2. What are some accessible books for learning its proof, with or without pseudodifferential operators? (For example, I believe this result is contained in Hörmander's tetralogy on linear PDEs, but it could be very difficult to study from those books...)

Comment: In general it follows from local elliptic regularity in Euclidean space by freezing the coefficients. Have you tried to look at "Fredholm operators and Einstein metrics on conformally compact manifolds" by John Lee. Lemma 4.8 seems to be what you need.

Comment: See section 10.3.2  of   https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf  The regularity part is proved only  for first order operators. The general strategy is outlined  and references are provided.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu In fact, this question arose when I was reading your notes (which by the way are very well written!). However, it seems that one has to read hundreds of pages on pseudodifferential operators to get this specific result. I wonder if there are easier proofs available...

Comment: Perhaps this is in the work of Agmon-Douglis-Nirenberg.

Comment: @Colescu  That was my problem. I was not able to produce a reasonably succinct  proof of the regularity other than in those two cases.  As Deane Yang  pointed out, the first complete proof of $L^p$-regularity is in the papers of Agmon-Douglis-Nirenberg  that deal with operators acting on vector valued functions. For scalar operators you can find a shorter proof in the book Bers_John-Shechter *Partial Differential Equations*. Both sources construct a parametrix of sorts. Everything reduces to the Calderon-Zygmund inequality.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments! I'm very surprised that there does not seem to be any textbook account of the complete proof of this elegant result...